# p:selectOneMenu preselects previous item when noSelectionOption item is present

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facelets, selected, selectonemenu

There is a problem with `p:selectOneMenu` selection when adding a `f:selectItem`.

View:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{selectionTest.selectedName}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{selectionTest.allNames}" var="varName" itemLabel="#{varName}" itemValue="#{varName}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Model:

```
private List<String> allNames;
private String selectedName;

public MenuSelectionTestBean(){
    allNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    allNames.add("Ahmed");
    allNames.add("Mohamed");
    allNames.add("Ibrahim");
    allNames.add("Walid");

    selectedName ="Walid";
}
```

Result:

[image]

The item "Walid" should be selected, however "Ibrahim" is selected instead. I think that PrimeFaces selects the item depending on its index in the list and not the value of the item.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could reproduce your problem. I looked in the PrimeFaces source code. It's a bug in PrimeFaces `SelectOneMenuRenderer` which exposes only when  an item with `noSelectionOption="true"` is been used. The renderer won't generate the HTML `<option>` element of the backing `<select>` element for that, but it will generate the `<li>` of the visual `<ul>` list for that. In other words, the `<select>` contains in your case 4 items and the `<ul>` 5 items. The `<li>` is selected by JavaScript based on the index of the `<option selected>`, exactly as you suspected. That explains your problem.

Your best bet is to [report it as a bug](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues) to PrimeFaces guys. The renderer should also generate the `<option>` for that, or the JavaScript should select the option based on value instead of on index.

In the meanwhile, replacing the `noSelectionOption="true"` by `itemValue="#{null}"`, or also `itemValue=""` when JSF is configured to interpret empty string submitted values as `null`, should solve your problem.

Comment: it is realy an issue http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4178&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20TargetVersion%20Reporter%20Owner%20Summary&start=100 i found it after posting this problem; thanks