# Execute some code when a value from a p:selectOneMenu is selected

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, listener, selectonemenu

I am doing a password editor. The password can be entered in two ways: manually entering the values for password and confirmation or by selecting some already generated password.

To use the generated password, a new value from the select box must be chosen. The change triggers the filling of the password/confirmation fields(`psw1` and `psw2`) with the value from the selected value.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{password.selectedPassword}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{password.passwords}" var="val"
        itemLabel="#{val}" itemValue="#{val}" />
        <p:ajax update="psw1, psw2" listener="#{password.passwordChanged}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

I need to implement the filling of password fields also when the the same value is selected. How can I implement this? One way is to add an extra value, a default empty value.

Comment: What do you mean by _I need to implement the filling of password fields also when the the same value is selected_?

Comment: @patstuart: when the currently selected value (i.e. the default value) is re-selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't trigger a `change` event if the value has not changed. Indeed, one way is to supply a default value as in *"Please select"* with a `#{null}` value or even with `noSelectionOption="true"` in flavor of an additional `<f:selectItem>`. This forces the enduser to actually change the value to a valid value.

E.g.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{password.selectedPassword}" >
    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--select--" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{password.passwords}" var="val"
        itemLabel="#{val}" itemValue="#{val}" />
        <p:ajax update="psw1, psw2" listener="#{password.passwordChanged}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Another way is to use `<p:selectOneListbox>` instead, which is maybe better if you don't have many items.

```
<p:selectOneListbox value="#{password.selectedPassword}" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{password.passwords}" var="val"
        itemLabel="#{val}" itemValue="#{val}" />
        <p:ajax update="psw1, psw2" listener="#{password.passwordChanged}"/>
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

Comment: To add, FYI: I've run into a bug in the past trying to get `noSelectItem` to work for `<p:selectOneMenu>`. I don't know if the bug is in PrimeFaces or MyFaces 2.

Comment: @patstuart: indeed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110755/pselectonemenu-preselects-previous-item-when-noselectionoption-item-is-present/ Bug was in PF by the way.

Comment: You overtook me! Congratulations on being number 3